# How to delete a row from datatables and mysql in the same time?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using Datatables to list some data into a table. I figured out how to make the delete row work in the Datatables but I can not figure out how to make delete at the same time from the MySQL database. Not being deleted from there, on refresh will get the JSON file again that will populate my table. This is my code so far: (I am trying to get the ID of the row I am pressing the delete from, match the id with the one in the database and delete the one from the database)

This function executes when the delete button is pressed:

```
// Add an action delete record
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button.delete', function () {
    table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw();

    // AJAX Request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'app/getcv.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { "data": "id" },
        success: function(data){

            alert("jjjjj");
            // table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
        }
    }) 
} );
```

Comment: Implement af serverside endpoint you can call that deletes the row in the database. This is the only meaningful answer, you cannot expect more help. DataTables is strict clientside (even if you are using a serverside script) and no one in the world can guess how your backend works. If you can create a `app/getcv.php` you can also create a `app/deletecv.php` ...

Answer (score 0):

on Click Call your Delete Methods as soon as it clicked Delete the record from the database then romove the list

Comment: This is what I can’t figure out how to do! Can you show me an example with something working? Cos I believe the php is not read!